# Uniformly convergence of collections of functions

Tags: real-analysis

What is exactly uniformly convergence's definition.

I see this $f_t:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ then with some conditons we can conclude $f_t$ are uniformly converges to g whenever $t\to0$.

But this is different from common definition for uniformly convergence:

We say the sequence ${\displaystyle (f_{n})_{n\in \mathbb {N} }}$ is uniformly convergent on ${\displaystyle E}$ with limit$ {\displaystyle f:E\to \mathbb {R} }$ if for every ${\displaystyle \epsilon >0,}$ there exists a natural number ${\displaystyle N}$ such that for all ${\displaystyle n\geq N} $ and ${\displaystyle x\in E}$

${\displaystyle |f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon .} $

Answer (score 1):

You just modify the definition slightly:

> The family of functions $\{f_t\}_{t\in I}$ (where $I$ is say an open interval containing the origin) converges to $f$, uniformly on $E\subset\Bbb{R}$, as $t\to 0$, if the following condition is satisfied:
>
> - for every $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that for all $0<|t|<\delta$, we have $\|f_t-f\|_{\infty,E}<\epsilon$. Here, $\|f\|_{\infty,E}:=\sup\limits_{x\in E}|f(x)|$.

The fact that we put $0<|t|<\delta$ reflects the "as $t\to 0$" part of the definition. The uniformity of the convergence on $E$ is encoded in the use of the sup norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty,E}$ on $E$ rather than some pointwise value like $|f_t(x)-f(x)|$ for $x\in E$.

Answer (score 0):

${\displaystyle (f_{t})}$ is uniformly convergent on ${\displaystyle E}$ with limit ${\displaystyle f:E\to \mathbb {R} }$ as $t \to 0$ if for every ${\displaystyle \epsilon >0}$, there exists ${\displaystyle r>0}$ such that for  ${\displaystyle 0<t\leq r}$ and ${\displaystyle x\in E}$ we have

${\displaystyle |f_{t}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon .} $

Answer (score 0):

This definition is not far away from the definition for sequences of functions. For any sequence $t_n$ convergent to $0$ the sequence of functions $f_{t_n}$ is convergent uniformly to $f.$